# Where or when to call RemoveObserver

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, nsnotificationcenter

I have a UITextView subclass where I add an NSNotificationCenter observer. But where do I remove the observer again?

My code:

```
_textDidChangeNotification = UITextView.Notifications.ObserveTextDidChange(TextDidChange);
```

In Objective C I would do it in the dealloc method but I am not sure where to do the same in C#

As I understand the documentation I should call

```
_textDidChangeNotification.Dispose()
```

I have tried to have a

```
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(disposing);
        if (disposing)
        {
            _textDidChangeNotification.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

but it is never called.

The complete class, as requested:

```
public class PlaceholderTextView : UITextView
{
    public string Placeholder 
    { 
        get { return PlaceholderLabel.Text; }
        set
        { 
            PlaceholderLabel.Text = value; 
            PlaceholderLabel.SizeToFit();
        }
    }

    protected UILabel PlaceholderLabel { get; set; }

    protected NSObject _textDidChangeNotification;

    public override string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return base.Text;
        }
        set
        {
            base.Text = value;
            AdjustPlaceholderHidden();
        }
    }

    public PlaceholderTextView() 
    {
        SetupLayout();

        _textDidChangeNotification
        = UITextView.Notifications.ObserveTextDidChange(TextDidChange);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(disposing);
        _textDidChangeNotification.Dispose();
    }

    protected void SetupLayout()
    {
        PlaceholderLabel = new UILabel(new CGRect(0, 9, 0, 0));
        PlaceholderLabel.TextColor = UIColor.FromWhiteAlpha(0.702f, 1f);

        AddSubview(PlaceholderLabel);
    }

    protected void AdjustPlaceholderHidden()
    {
        if (Text.Length > 0)
        {
            PlaceholderLabel.Hidden = true;
        }
        else
        {
            PlaceholderLabel.Hidden = false;
        }
    }

    protected void TextDidChange(object sender, Foundation.NSNotificationEventArgs args)
    {
        AdjustPlaceholderHidden();
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in `ViewWillDisappear` like so:

```
public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewWillAppear (animated);

        SubscribeMessages ();
    }

    public override void ViewWillDisappear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewWillDisappear(animated);
        UnSubscribeMessages ();
    }

    public void SubscribeMessages ()
    {
        _hideObserver = NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(UIKeyboard.WillHideNotification, OnKeyboardNotification);
        _showObserver = NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(UIKeyboard.WillShowNotification, OnKeyboardNotification);
    }

    public void UnSubscribeMessages ()
    {
        if (_hideObserver != null) NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.RemoveObserver (_hideObserver);
        if (_showObserver != null) NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.RemoveObserver(_showObserver);
    }
```

or `ViewDidDisappear` like in the Xamarin sample code [here](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/blob/2551e963841bad6531069d7f574578b3bdc4abd8/MonoCatalogSample/textview.cs#L68)

**Update**
I see what you mean now, I would suspect that something is preventing the custom view from being garbage collected. Have you had a look at this [blog post](https://krumelur.me/2015/04/27/xamarin-ios-the-garbage-collector-and-me/) it might help.

Also from this [sample code](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/blob/2551e963841bad6531069d7f574578b3bdc4abd8/SimpleTextInput/EditableCoreTextView.cs#L53) it looks like you are calling the dispose correctly but they null out the custom view on `ViewDidUnload` [here](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/blob/2551e963841bad6531069d7f574578b3bdc4abd8/SimpleTextInput/SimpleTextInputViewController.cs#L35):

Comment: The class in question is a subclass of UIView (UITextView) so there is no ViewWillDisappear or ViewDidDisappear or similar.

Comment: What do you add the UITextView to? can you call dispose on the UITextView in whatever you add the view to?

Comment: Sure I could do it all manually all the way from the UIViewController at the top. But then this would not be a normal UIView. If it was Objective C I could just do it in the dealloc method

Comment: Can you post complete code so that we can have a look